# How can I make two divs of the same class move across the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want certain divs to move across the screen in Javascript, a bit like [this website](http://worldseasiestdecision.org/en-us/) (scroll down), only horizontally, or like [here](http://onedollarlesson.com/) (also vertical, but I would love it horizontal)

here is my HTML:

```
<div id = "creators" class = "big-part">
    <h3>Creators</h3>
    <div class = "creator_name">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "creator_name">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "creator_name">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <p>Text</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.big-part {
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    background-color: #3c3c91;
    border-radius: 21px;
    padding: 0.5% 1.5%; 
    margin-top: 2%;
}
.creator_name {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    height: 300px;
    color: #3c3c91;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 1%;
}
.creator_name {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2% 2%;
}
```

and my javascript that is in a `script` tag:

```
var creatorEl= document.getElementsByClassName("creator_name");

var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var moveTheDiv = function() {
    var currTime = new Date().getTime();
    var secondsElapsed = ((currTime - startTime)/1000);
    var newLeft = parseFloat(secondsElapsed) * 30 + "px";
    creatorEl.style.left = newLeft;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(walkTheCat);
};
moveTheDiv();
```

Thanks!

By the way, it would be great for this animation to happen only when the client/user has scrolled down and the div is visible.
You can answer half of the question if you want, I will take any help.

**EDIT**:
I can make them move only if I add an ID to each and move them with the ID, is there a way to move them both at the same time but only using a class?

Comment: Are you looking for some parallax scrolling plugins?

Comment: no, just a moving div

Comment: What is wrong with your currnet code?

Comment: Look under jquery animate

Comment: have you seen how `getElementsByClassName` works? . . it will return a collection of all elements with the specified class.. so you should filter those elements before targeting it to move

Answer (score 0):

You may find the animation engine Velocity.js helpful. http://julian.com/research/velocity/ (I'm not affiliated with the creator).

You implement functions similar to the jQuery's .animate() method.

Here is an example of how to spin a div:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('#divToAnimate').velocity(
    { rotateX: "+=0", 
      rotateY: "+=360",
      height: '+=50px',
      width: '+=100px'
    }, 
    {
      duration:4000,
      loop:false,
      easing:'linear'
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample animation with Velocity.js</title>

  <!-- jQuery CDN -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <!-- Velocity.js CDN -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="divToAnimate">Example Div to Animate</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope helpful and good luck!